# Automation Studio File Drop source from external FTP

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, ftp

Setting up an automation to occur on file drop but it appears the only options for directory choice are in the import folder or the legacy triggered automations folder.

The file that I'm dropping is actually dropping to a different business unit's FTP (the parent).  Is there any way to select a different FTP directory for the `File drop starting source`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, it is not possible. The listener for this is only viable on SFMC Import folder and those subdirectories below it.

Now, it is possible to 'fake' this, but it requires your 3rd party system to drop the main file on your external FTP and then drop an empty or small file to SFMC SFTP folder when that file is finished being uploaded.

To elaborate:

1. Set up a Triggered Automation (select your desired folder and file name pattern for the 'dummy' file)
2. Set your import activity to pull from the external FTP to grab the
   data file
3. Create the activity in your 3rd party data system to first drop the data file to your external FTP.
4. After this file has finished loading, have it shoot over a dummy file to the SFMC to trigger the automation.

**Another option** if your system can send API calls is to:

1. Have a 'scheduled' automation set up with the import activity but do not schedule it.
2. You then have your external system shoot over an [Automation Studio
   API call](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/189603/how-to-trigger-an-automation-from-another-automation) to start the automation once the file has finished uploading
   to the FTP.
3. Your Automation runs, importing the file from the external FTP.

Both of these are a bit much and require a good amount of extra work. Unless it is necessary to store this file elsewhere, I would adjust the process to drop it to SFMC instead.

Comment: Really helpful.  The reason for the ask is my external system (Dell Boomi) has a limited amount of connector licenses (already maxed out) and I was hoping I could rig it to grab files from the Parent BU's FTP.   You're right - easiest and best option is to just purchase more connection licenses.

Comment: Another possible solution: have the file drop activity on the parent and instead of an import, do a file transfer to the import folder of a child BU into the import folder there.  Thoughts?

Comment: NOPE!  FileTransfer activity doesn't work that way.  You CAN use a shared FTP across other BU's.  This is the route I'll go.