# Child Automation run as step in Parent Automation?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, automationstudio, marketingcloudapi

Any ideas on using this [SSJS Automation Trigger](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/189603/how-to-trigger-an-automation-from-another-automation) (or some other method) to Trigger a Child Automation as a middle step in a Parent Automation that once complete continues to process?

I have a long (many steps) Automation that needs to be run during several different other Automations, I don't really want to put all the Child steps into each Parent from a readability and maintainability perspective.

I tried a do while loop in the linked SSJS code;

```
        do {
            // Keep getting the status until it changes from Running
            automationObject = GetAutomationObject(automationCustomerKey);
        } while (automationObject.Status == 3);
        // This should mean the Automation has completed running
        Write("Automation Complete");
```

But this didn't work, probably because it's horribly inefficient. There is no option to set a delay in SSJS for a polling interval last time I tried either.

Any genius ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Although there is no way to accurately make what you are asking, if you instead break up each part into multiple automations to accomplish the same tasks, it can be possible.

For instance instead of:

**Parent Automation**
Step 1 - Step 2 - Step 3 - Step 4 (child) - Step 5 - Step 6 - Step 7 (child) - Step 8

It would be:

**Auto 1**
Step 1 - Step 2 - Step 3 - Step 4 (calls Auto 2)

**Auto 2**
Step 5 - Step 6 - Step 7 (calls Auto 3)

**Auto 3**
Step 8

In order to track this, I would have a fourth Automation that runs a script activity to verify that the other automations are running on schedule.  This could be attained a couple ways:

1. API calls to get last run date, last instance status and current status and then take action to alert if there is issue (I would also log the results into a DE)
2. Have an activity at the end of each Automation that inserts the current datetime into a DE and then do a script activity that looks there to validate that the datetime displayed there fits into the expected results. Then send an alert if this is not correct.

**Example to call automation**:

```
<script runat="server">

Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");

//gg_DELETEME
var autoCustomerKey = "my_autoKey"

try{
    var retrieve = retrieveAuto(autoCustomerKey)
    var autoObjectID = retrieve.Results[0].ObjectID;
    var Status = retrieve.Results[0].Status;

    if (autoObjectID != "null") {

        if (Status == 2) {
            var perform = performAuto(autoObjectID);
        }

        if (Status == 3) {
            do {

                var retrieve = retireveAuto(autoCustomerKey)
                var autoObjectID = retrieve.Results[0].ObjectID;
                var Status = retrieve.Results[0].Status;

                if (Status == 2) {
                    var perform = performAuto(autoObjectID);
                } 

            } while (Status != 2)  
        }

    } else {
       Platform.Function.RaiseError("Automation " + automationCustomerKey + " not found", false);
    }

} catch(e) {
    Write(Stringify(e))
}

function performAuto(autoObjectID) {
    var prox2 = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
    var action = "Start";
    var props = {
    ObjectID: autoObjectID
    };
    var opts = {};
    var perfRes = prox.performItem("Automation", props, action, opts);

    return perfRes;
}

function retrieveAuto(autoCustomerKey) {
    var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();

    var cols = ["Name","ProgramID","Status"];
    var filter = {
    Property: "CustomerKey",
    SimpleOperator: "equals",
    Value: autoCustomerKey
    };
    var res = prox.retrieve("Automation", cols, filter);

    return res;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! This would be fine if there was only one parent and child but I have something like (P=Parent, S=Step, C=Child);
`P1S1 - P1S2 - C1S1-16 - P1S3 - P1S4;
P2S1 - P2S2 - C1S1-16 - P2S3 - P2S4;
P3S1 - P3S2 - C1S1-16 - P3S3 - P3S4;`
etc
So the Child Automation needs to call a different final automation in your example.
Although you've touched on a good idea, I could use a DE record to track which Parent called the Child and then have the Child call the appropriate final Parent steps based on the value in the DE... Something to think about whether I could make it robust enough... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot think of a way other than along the lines of what you are doing. That said, the problem I see with it is that, while waiting for the child automation, this script can timeout after 30 mins.

Overall I think the best way to handle this would be to have the child automation trigger a third automation to complete the remaining activities. There’s not really a good way to keep a true parent process.

Answer (score 0):

The 'do while' SSJS solution actually works when running this as a Script Activity instead of as a Cloud Page (since the Cloud Page times out quickly). Though I also used an external website with a simple custom page that could mimic a delay for polling the automation status with a reasonable frequency;

```
        var runRequestResult = RunAutomation(automationObject.ObjectID);
        if (runRequestResult == 'OK') {
            Write("<br>Automation Started.");
            var counter = 1;
            var waitms = 10000; // how long in ms to wait between polling the Automation
            do {
                // Wait for X ms, the counter parameter will prevent the page from being cached
                var req = new Script.Util.HttpGet("http://externalwebsite.com/wait.aspx?w=" + waitms + "&counter=" + counter);
                var resp = req.send();
                Write("<br>Waiting... " + counter);
                counter++;
                // Refresh the Automation Object
                automationObject = GetAutomationObject(automationCustomerKey);
            } while (automationObject.Status == 3); // Keep looping while the Automation is still running
            Write("<br>Automation Finished.");
        }
```

Note there is a 30 minute limit on Script Activities timing out, so the Child Automation must complete within that time.