# The same Fire event more than once in one Marketing Cloud Automation?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, automationstudio

In Journey Builder, we need to evaluate entries to a Data Extension every 15 minutes.

We programmed a sequence in Automation Studio which includes:

1. SQL Query - Adds new data to the Data Extension which is the JB Entry source
2. fire event
3. 15 min. wait
4. SQL Query
5. fire event
6. 15 min. wait
7. SQL Query
8. fire event
9. 15 min. wait
10. SQL Query
11. fire event

But the fire events do not inject the new contacts to the Journey.

Any idea of why, or how this can be achieved?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me - is the first event injecting a record?

Comment: each SQL Query queries "live data" added in the background. The SQL Query adds data to the DE used by Journey Builder. @JonasLamberty

Answer (score 3):

Journey Builder, when configured in the entry event accordingly, listens to the run of an *automation*, not individual activities.

Your automation schema contains multiple *automation activities* from which you expect a result. This expectation is incorrect. You should get ONE injection into the journey once the automation is *finished*, which is your step 11.

So what are your options?

Either: question the latency requirement. Run hourly, inject hourly with one automation.

Or: Run **four** automations in a 15 minute offset. They do not "wait" for each other but run independently.
Caution. automation runs are technically billable, although not currently enforced. This seems to be a safeguard against abuse at this time, which is not guaranteed to stay like this. To give you an idea, one hourly automation consumes around 8.7k runs per year. Corporate Edition offers 45k. So you have around 5 hourly automations in that contractual setup. This pattern would use four for one single process.

Or: Run two alternating automations that call each other via SSJS and execute the sql + fire sequence, and you can even save yourself the wait, theoretically. automation runs are still technically billable, and this could be a LOT of automations, even more than in the previous pattern. Use this VERY sparingly.  [How to trigger an automation from another automation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/189603/how-to-trigger-an-automation-from-another-automation)

Or: Question the pattern of using sql / automations entirely and instead leverage the API & API Events.

Comment: Thanks @Jonas, I wasn't aware that automations are billable! The downside of running 4 automations vs. one - is that we actually need to set up 4 journeys, since Journey Builder is subscribed to only 1 automation. If we go the SSJS path, we'll have 1 automation running hourly, with 15-min. period to call another automation via SSJS. This is the 5 hourly automation limit. 
Adam's script mentions a CustomerKey-Of-Automation - is that the ExternalKey? IF not, where do I find it? Also, does the automation we call from SSJS has to be "Active"? or can it be paused?

Comment: Also, if we can't use the fire event like I described, how can one use the fire event? Is this a legacy functionality being depricated?

Comment: The entire multiplication options are not preferable, to be honest. Options 1 and 4 is what I would consider. The billable thing you can check in the  marketing cloud edition overview. for automation it's not an enforced, nor a  hard limit, but this kind of tells you that you are doing something weird when you multiply automations. customerkey in that script is externalkey, yes.  The automation you call has to have a schedule, but must NOT run. if you can press "run once" on the UI, that is a good sign, because thats what the API call does.

Comment: fire event: forget it. this is now done differently. go to your journey schedule, set it to "automation", and your automation has to target the journey DE to show up here. Select it. Finish and activate the Journey. This automatically places the replacement for the "fire event" in the automation at the last step. Make sure you don't have the automation open in another tab or so, this will make it behave weird. No idea why all this is not properly documented, but that's how it works. Activation of journey creates the automation event.

Comment: Thanks again! The use case is to be able to send a Push notif. for booked classes (Yoga, etc.) 1 hour before the class actually begins; Bookings can happen all the time - and we update the Booking Table with API Calls in Real-time. The automation idea was to leverage SQL to query the bookings that would start from now+1 hour to now+1h15 min - sending the push after. Option #1 will send messages too early for classes that start at XX:45 for example.The granularity for Waiting by attribute is daily. So our best option is #4: let another system calculate WHEN the push needs to be sent?

Comment: In that case, I would think so. But before you do that - If all you plan to do is send one email, you could also just forget about the journey, and just send directly from automation studio in your initial post's sequence, replacing all fire events with sendouts.

Comment: It's a Push Notif...  :) Possible? I don't see a Push Activity provisioned (I don't think there is one in Automation Studio); If not, maybe a script in Automation Studio to fire a push to DE members?

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_mp_use_mobilepush_with_automation_studio.htm&type=5

Comment: !!!!! LIFE SAVER !!!!!  MUCHAS GRACIAS !!!! My bad, should have found it. (Putting myself in the corner). Funny I cannot see this as an option under Automation Studio > Activities, but can see this Activity (and many more) available within an actual Automation, When building the Workflow.