# Extracting ObjectID of an Automation

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, wsproxy

I am not sure what I have done wrong but I am not able to extract the ObjectID of an Automation.

Here is my code

```js
var prox1 = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
  var cols = [ "Name", "ObjectID", "CustomerKey" ];
  var filter = {
      Property: "Name",
      SimpleOperator: "Equals",
      Value: "[Name_of_Automation]"
  };
  var desc = prox1.retrieve("Automation", cols, filter);

  // Output ObjectID if you want to see it. 
  Write('<br>ObjectID: ' + desc.Results[0].ObjectID);
```

The result is always

```
ObjectID: null
```

I also tried listing all the Automations using the code provided on [AmpScript.xyz](https://ampscript.xyz/how-tos/how-to-use-wsproxy-to-work-with-automations-in-server-side-javascript/), and the Stringify result showed all the objects have "ObjectID: null".

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to include "ProgramID" in cols.

```js
<script type="javascript" runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core",1)
var prox1 = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
  var cols = [ "Name", "ProgramID", "CustomerKey" ];
  var filter = {
      Property: "Name",
      SimpleOperator: "Equals",
      Value: "test"
  };
  var desc = prox1.retrieve("Automation", cols, filter);

  // Output ObjectID if you want to see it. 
  Write('<br>ObjectID: ' + desc.Results[0].ObjectID);
</script>
```

Comment: It works! Thanks Jonas. How did you know that is "ProgramID" mind I ask?

Comment: most importantly I had reference examples where SOAP API was used, which is emulated by WSproxy.  https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/189603/how-to-trigger-an-automation-from-another-automation + in the API docs you can see that there is no ObjectID on the automation object, but ProgramID does have the same description as Data Extension's ObjectID. CustomObject and Program are the names used in some places for DE and Automation respectively, so from there it's connecting dots.; https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/automation.htm

Comment: Reading SFMC documentation is like a Sherlock Holmes game :)